# How to declare user defined properties in pom.xml file

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables, pom.xml, ui-automation

I am using maven project for UI automation and I need to run some tests in multiple environment and multiple browsers.
I have created added the pom.xml file and declared the properties in it. But when i execute it through the terminal i get errors.
command i used-

`mvn clean`

`mvn test -Denvironment=test -Dbrowser=chrome`

**My Xml file-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ui-automation-projects</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <property>
            <environment>${environment}</environment>
        </property>
        <property>
            <browser>${browser}</browser>>
        </property>
    </properties>


    <dependencies> </dependencies>
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**Error-**
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM D:\work\Cucumber_Projects\ui-automation-projects\pom.xml: TEXT must be immediately followed by END_TAG and not START_TAG (position: START_TAG seen ...\n            ... @13:26)  @ line
13, column 26

Comment: Remove <property>, leave everything under <properties>. I don't remember having a <property> tag

Comment: I will add my comment as an answer, please upvote it and set as answer, my comment being the first answer to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must delete `<property>` and add your property under `<properties>`.

```
<properties>
     <environment>${environment}</environment>
     <browser>${browser}</browser>

 </properties>
```

Also, you have an extra '>' after `</browser>`

Comment: Thank you @Tudor Grigoriu for the answer. It worked and i was able to execute the mvn test command with out error. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Project properties in pom.xml are declared like this:

```
<properties>
    <environment>default-environemnt-value</environment>
    <browser>default-browser-value</browser>>
</properties>
```

You can read more in [POM reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties)

Answer (score -1):

You have error during the parson pom.xml file I checked it into my Idea and corrected. You didn't have `</project>` tag and `<dependencies> </dependencies>` were redundant. Also there should be answer

```
<properties>
    <environment>${envValue}</environment>
    <browser>${browserValue}</browser>
</properties>
```

After this the file builds correctly.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ui-automation-projects</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
      <environment>${envValue}</environment>
      <browser>${browserValue}</browser>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score -3):

I have seen u r POM couple of ties and have seen my local pom how I have defined my dependencies and POM
I found 2 things

1. You have defined the properties already in which u can directly add the value
   (Here in your case it is environment and Browser)
   else define alone as follows in properties
   ${environment}
2. I haven't seen end for the Project in the POM.
   Try adding that and that should work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH1Ht.png)